# MySQL++ returns nothing

Tags: c++, mysql, mysql++

I have recently decided to learn `MySQL++` and have had some trouble getting started. Anyways, I am trying to make a program that stores most recent versions of programs (to help with Homebrew).

main.cpp:

```
#include <mysql++/mysql++.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace mysqlpp;

int main() {
    Connection conn (false);
    conn.connect ("db.ssqls", "localhost");
    Query query = conn.query();
    query << "SELECT * FROM version;";
    StoreQueryResult ares = query.store();
    for (size_t i = 0; i < ares.num_rows(); i++)
        cout << "Name: " << ares[i]["name"] << " - Address: " << ares[i]["address"] << endl;
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

I compiled this with `g++ -lmysqlpp -g main.cpp -o main -DMYSQLPP_MYSQL_HEADERS_BURIED`. I then ran this using `./main`.

Running `SELECT * FROM version;` on db.ssqls using `sqlite3` gives `1|cmake|3|11|0|cmake.org|`.

I was debugging (with `lldb`) this when I noticed that `ares.num_rows()==0`. In fact, it seems as if nothing happened.

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You've turned off exceptions, so you should the return value from  `conn.connect`. You may not be connected.

Comment: @user4581301 it is returning 0. I had exceptions before and nothing was thrown. (I'm assuming `int test = conn.connect("db.ssqls", "localhost");` is what you mean, right?)

Comment: `bool test = conn.connect("db.ssqls", "localhost");` would be a bit more appropriate, but getting a 0 is good enough. 0 is false. Documentation on this is <expletive deleted> weak, but I'd assume false means no connection. Apologies if i'm wrong. Test with 
a call to `connected`.

Comment: @user4581301 both return 0. I will fiddle around with the connection and see if I can fix it. Also, I started with their example (which requires other example code deleted in 2013ish) so I can completely understand frustration with the developers effort on that part of the library.

Comment: @user4581301 um... well this is embarrassing. Um... I *might* have *possibly* not known that you had to have a *cough cough* `mysqld` process running to accept the connections.

Comment: Smurf happens. Earlier today I recommended to someone that they use `release` rather than `reset` on a `unique_ptr`. Yipes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, turns out you need to have a `MySQL` server before running the `MySQL` commands. You need to have `mysqld` running on your computer.